# Magento 2: Internal link on product detail page to tab

Tags: magento2, product-view, product-tab

I have a series of custom tabs on a Magento 2 product details page that were setup via the catalog_product_view.xml file.

I am trying to setup a button that will allow me to link from the short description area to additional tab.

If I do a brand new request to `<a href="https://domain.com/product.html#additional">Additional</a>` - it works fine, but reloads the entire page.

If I do an internal link to `<a href="#additional">Additional</a>` it does not work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should do just trigger a click event for the tab on your button click if you just want to display on click like

add below script in your details.phtml file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        require([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
        'use strict';
            $("#your-button-id").on("click" ,function() {
//                console.log('48');
                //your a tag id like below
                $("#tab-label-reviews-title").trigger( "click" );
            });
});
</script>
```

run this commans

> php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: This worked. One thing I had to contend with was that my custom tab had a period in the id, so I had to rename it so that jquery wouldn't flake out.